# Why snmpv3 get PDU returned successfully with a not existed OID?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

When I using SNMP4J to simulate the snmpv3's GET PDU, I found that although I add a not-existed OID to the variable binding list, I still get a valid response.
But when the protocol version is **v1**, **I got the error code 2** , means 'no such name'.
When the protocol version is **v2c**, **I didn't GET ERROR**, and returned vb list size is 1, and the list(0) variable binding 's syntax is exception ,which means "no such object". 
So I can figure out whether it exists or not when using the v1 or v2c, but when it's v3, I got the following response:

```
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs.0 = Counter32: xx
```

**xx is a number.

The code is :

```
        import org.snmp4j.*;
        import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
        import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
        import org.snmp4j.security.*;
        import org.snmp4j.smi.*;
        import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;

          import static org.snmp4j.mp.MPv3.createLocalEngineID;

    /**
     *
     *  Following syntax may helpfull:  SMIConstants
     *    public static final int EXCEPTION_NO_SUCH_OBJECT = BER.NOSUCHOBJECT;
     *    public static final int EXCEPTION_NO_SUCH_INSTANCE = BER.NOSUCHINSTANCE;
     *    public static final int EXCEPTION_END_OF_MIB_VIEW = BER.ENDOFMIBVIEW;
     *
     * give a string and test whether it exists or not
     *
     * Conclusions:
     * (1)When the op is GET,
     *    V1:
     *    errorcode at pdu, AND IS 2, MEANS "no such name"
     *    V2C:
     *    NOT GET ERROR, and returned vb list size is 1, and the list(0) Null.isExceptionSyntax(vb.getSyntax()) == true // means "no such object"
     *    V3:
     *    NOT GET ERROR, like this : SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs.0 = Counter32: 23
     *    returned varbingds : 1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.3.0 = xxx
     *  (2)When the op is GETNEXT:
     *     V1:
     *     errorcode at pdu, AND IS 2, MEANS "no such name"
     *     V2C:
     *     NOT GET ERROR, and returned vb list size is 1, and the list(0) Null.isExceptionSyntax(vb.getSyntax()) == true // means "endOfMibView"
     *     V3:
     *     NOT GET ERROR, like this : SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs.0 = Counter32: 23
     *  (3)When the op is GETBULK:
     *
     * Created by edward.gao on 8/9/16.
     */
    public class TestOidExists {

    private static final String _V1_OR_V2_COMMUNITYNAME= "public";
    private static final String _V3_USERNAME = "edward";
    /**
     * authentication protocol MD5 or SHA
     */
    private static final String _V3_AUTHENTICATION_PASSPHRASE = "auth12345678";

    /**
     * privacy protocol DES OR AES
     */
    private static final String _V3_PRIVACY_PASSPHRASE = "encry12345678";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        final String addrString= "udp:192.168.170.150/161";
        byte [] localEngineID = createLocalEngineID();
        //version3 need usm
        USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),new OctetString(localEngineID), 0);
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());

        snmp.listen();


        String [] oids = new String[] {/*".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.6.3.1.2", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5",*/ ".1.3.999"};
        String [] types = new String[]{ "get","getnext", "getbulk"};
        for (String oid : oids)
        {
            for (String type : types) {
                System.out.println(String.format("VERSION IS 3, oid:%s result: %d", oid, typeOfOID(oid, snmp, SnmpConstants.version3, type)));
                System.out.println(String.format("VERSION IS 2, oid:%s result: %d", oid, typeOfOID(oid, snmp, SnmpConstants.version2c, type)));
                System.out.println(String.format("VERSION IS 1, oid:%s result: %d", oid, typeOfOID(oid, snmp, SnmpConstants.version1, type)));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * get the type of matched oid string
     * @param oid
     * @param snmp
     * @return  -1 : not exist , 0, leaf, 1, tree
     */
    public static int typeOfOID(String oid , Snmp snmp, int version, String typeString)  throws  Exception
    {


        boolean isv3 = version == SnmpConstants.version3;
        //build a client
        Address addr = GenericAddress.parse("192.168.170.150/161");
        Target target = null;
        if (isv3) {
            UsmUser usmUser = new UsmUser(new OctetString(_V3_USERNAME),
                    AuthMD5.ID,
                    new OctetString(_V3_AUTHENTICATION_PASSPHRASE),
                    PrivDES.ID,
                    new OctetString(_V3_PRIVACY_PASSPHRASE)
            );
            snmp.getUSM().addUser(usmUser);
            target = new UserTarget();
        }
        else
        {
            target = new CommunityTarget();
            //the default version is 3
            if (version == SnmpConstants.version2c)
            {
                target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
            }
            else
            {
                target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
            }
            ((CommunityTarget)target).setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
        }


        target.setAddress(addr);
        target.setRetries(2);
        target.setTimeout(30000);

        int type = typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("get") ? PDU.GET : (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("getnext") ? PDU.GETNEXT : PDU.GETBULK);
        System.out.println("Using version " + (version == SnmpConstants.version1 ? "v1" :(version == SnmpConstants.version2c ? "v2c " : "v3 ")) + " type:" + typeString);
        PDU pdu = version == SnmpConstants.version3 ? new ScopedPDU() : new PDU();
        pdu.setType(type);
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oid)));
        pdu.setRequestID(new Integer32(0));
        ResponseEvent responseEvent = snmp.send(pdu, target);
        if (responseEvent.getError() == null)
        {
            PDU responsePdu = responseEvent.getResponse();
            if (responsePdu.getErrorStatus() == 0)
            {
                responsePdu.getVariableBindings().forEach(vb ->System.out.print(vb + " " + Null.isExceptionSyntax(vb.getSyntax())));
                System.out.println();
                //leaf get only one, other get more than one
                return responsePdu.getVariableBindings().size() == 1 ? 0 : 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("error code at pdu," +  responsePdu.getErrorStatus() + " text:" + responsePdu.getErrorStatusText() + " index:" + responsePdu.getErrorIndex());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("error happend,");
            responseEvent.getError().printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

***So my question is :

(1)Is this behavior of v3 correctly implemented ? Why didn't I get a some kind of error?

(2)How do I test whether the OID exists or not by using SNMP4J?***

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving so called **SNMP REPORT PDU**.  What happens is that the agent receives the request PDU from manager and determines that some important security attributes like `engine_id`, `engine_boots` and `engine_time` are missing and sends back a REPORT to notify the manager about that. The manager should process the REPORT PDU in full accordance with so called SNMP Engine Discovery procedure described in details in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5343.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1, When I set the securityName & securityLevel of the userTarget, it worked correctly.

```
        userTarget.setSecurityName(new OctetString(_V3_USERNAME));
        userTarget.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
```

And so For Question 2, it's the same with the version 1 & 2c now.

Reference : rfc3414:

> 3)  If the value of the msgAuthoritativeEngineID field in the
>       securityParameters is unknown then:
>       a) a non-authoritative SNMP engine that performs discovery may
>          optionally create a new entry in its Local Configuration
>          Datastore (LCD) and continue processing;
>   or
>       b) **the usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs counter is incremented**, and an
>          error indication (unknownEngineID) together with the OID and
>          value of the incremented counter is returned to the calling
>          module.